# SublimeText and React

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3

I'm new to React, I'm reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) tutorial an this is the code I'm writing:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class App extends React.Component {      

    render() {

        const person = {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe'
        };

        function formatName(user) {
            return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
        }

        function formatDate(date) {
            return date.toLocaleDateString();
        }

        function getGreeting(user) {
            if(user) {
                return <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>;
            }
            return <h1>Hello, Stranger.</h1>;
        }

        function tick() {
            const element = (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }

        function Welcome(props) {
            return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
        }
        function App() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Welcome name='Sara'/>
                    <Welcome name='Cahal'/>
                    <Welcome name='Edite'/>
                </div>
            );
        }

        // other code...

        const hi = <h1>{getGreeting(person)}</h1>;

        return (hi);
    } 
}
```

This is how I see the code:

[image]

Why the colors are in this form? In this way is difficult to read code.
How can I see colors like in the tutorial? 
Where I'm wrong? Is there a way to set React as language?

Comment: Check this link https://medium.com/@dwardmr/your-new-reactjs-on-sublime-text-3-workspace-setup-9ce87c12e93a

Comment: Since you've pasted the code from the tutorial/docs of React to Sublime Text, Sublime Text is showing you the above code because of the theme (default theme: monokai). You can look for various other themes at [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/theme). ST also supports a lot of packages which are specific to react, such as [ReactJS](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ReactJS)

Comment: @Think-Twice I read this article but it doesn't help me..

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I installed ReactJs package but it's the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need babel plugin for Sublime. It will give you es6 and jsx syntax highlighting. Just follow their documentation to enable it by default for your `.js` and `.jsx` files.

https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Cheers!